# Can we create an empty node(Directory) below the root node

Tags: java, swing, directory, jtree

Can we create an empty directy under the root node using dynamic JTree.
Eg:
   [image]

Am tyring to create a jtree like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (ADD_COMMAND.equals(command)) {
            //Add button clicked
            System.out.println("BUTTON CLICKED ");
              DefaultMutableTreeNode p3,p4;

              p3=treePanel.addObject("New Node " + newNodeSuffix++);
              treePanel.addObject(p3, "newDir",false);

        }

    }
    public void populateTree(DynamicTree treePanel) {
        String p1Name = new String("Parent 1");
        String p2Name = new String("Parent 2");
        String c1Name = new String("Child 1");
        String c2Name = new String("Child 2");

        DefaultMutableTreeNode p1, p2;

        p1 = treePanel.addObject(null, p1Name);
        p2 = treePanel.addObject(null, p2Name);

        treePanel.addObject(p1, c1Name);
        treePanel.addObject(p1, c2Name);

        treePanel.addObject(p2, c1Name);
        treePanel.addObject(p2, c2Name);
    }
```

On the button click event i cannot make directory without doing like this
 **DefaultMutableTreeNode p3,p4;

```
              p3=treePanel.addObject("New Node " + newNodeSuffix++);
              treePanel.addObject(p3, "newDir",false);**
```

As a result i got directory contain a file 
[image]

i want to avoid the newDir only empty directory is needed
please help me..........

Any help is appreciable.......

Thank you very much.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: _Is it possible...?_ Answer is: YES. But your question is overly too broad to be answered concisely. Follow Andrew's suggestion.

Comment: -1 for not clarifying the question: a) what _is_ DynamicTree b) what _do_ you want to achieve (sorry, but can't understand _avoid the newDir only empty directory is needed_) c) still no SSCCE. As is, the question is not answerable, so voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Define custom renderer to distinguish what is node (directory) and what is leaf (file). Use proper icons for nodes.

Comment: the question isn't overly clear - nevertheless nitpicking on this answer ;-) you _know_ that the default renderer already supports the distinction between folders and leafs. What else would a custom renderer do in the OP's context?

Comment: @kleopatra IMHO the author need to show leaf (directory without children files) as node (with proper icon). Where is my -1 from you?:-)

Comment: LOL - Yeah, that's how understand it as well - that's what askAllowsChildren is for (if I remember correctly)

Comment: @kleopatra I am not sure how the askAllowsChildren works if one leaf is node but another is not (in case of both allows children)